# Javascript What does "' + aStringVarible + '" (double quote plus single quote) do?

Tags: javascript

I saw this line of code from an online course:

```
photoHtml += '<a href="' + photo.link + '">';
```

Here, "photo" is an object, and photo.link is actually a url.

But it is my first time seeing people use "' together (I am new to javascript), so I am not sure what this does. My guessing is that it is a way to add quotations to a variable? Because if we directly put quotes around the variable photo.link, then it would not work as a variable, e.g. "photo.link"?

In python, I would use '"' + photo.link + '"' to deal with the case. So does "' + photo.link + '" do the same job here in javascript?

Thank you in advance! I know it is really amateur, but I tried to search on google, and did not find desired answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can define string literals either like this `'a string'` or `"a string"`. Both allow the other kind of character to be included without an escape character: `'"hello" world'` is a string containing `"hello" world`.

Answer (score 1):

The valid HTML produced by this will be something like

```
<a href="http://something.com/">
```

Notice that the quotes `"` delimit the link *url*.

Now, in JavaScript, regardless of the content of a string, the string in `photoHTML` is delimited by the quotes `'`. Thus, if you want your url to be a variable, you must somehow place it such that the produced html looks like this:

```
<a href="photo.link">
```

Where you want to *replace* the text `photo.link` with your actual link. This is achieved by:

```
photoHtml += '<a href="' + photo.link + '">';
```

where the `"` quotes delimit the url in the **html** and the `'` quotes delimit the string in the **JavaScript**.

Answer (score 0):

The `"` has nothing to do with it the concatenation. The `"` is for the attribute that is being rendered.

```
<a href="thelink">
        ^       ^
```

Answer (score 0):

The `value` of the `href` attribute has to be enclosed by quotation marks. It doesn't matter if it's a `'` single or a `"` double quotation mark.

In your example the `'` marks beginning and end of the javascript expression (string concatenation) while the `"` refers to the html attribute `href` and is part of the string itself.